# How do you capture/generate an image from a IPreviewHandler COMIMPORT in WPF/C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, windowsformshost

I was wondering if it is possible to generate an image (capture) of a ComImport object (like the Win7 PreviewHandler)?

I've tried to utilizing RenderTargetBitmap (on the parent control hosting the ComImport), as well as create a WinFormHost and using the DrawToBitmap method. Both however, proved useless as they would only show an empty frame.

Any help is appreciated!